# Excel : Return score based on location on spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to return a range of results based on the column that a word appears.

Eg. If apple appears in A=5, B=4, C=3, D=2, E=1. The word will only appear once across the spreadsheet so there won't be any duplicates.

Comment: Will it just be "apple" in the cell, or a few words, one of which is apple?

Comment: Will be a list of words, up to 60 across the columns but apple will only appear once.

Comment: Okay, say it appears in cell C1 then, does C1 contain "apple" or "more words than just apple"?

Comment: It could contain more than one word but that is set so specific terms can be entered, for instance I will also need to do the same thing for banana chips, the text within the cell is fixed but their position could change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=6-SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A:E))*COLUMN(A:E))
```